# Regex to list strings with no occurrence of special character '.' and having a space

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to filter out strings in project code which have the following form

```
'alphanumeric.alphanumeric.alphanumeric.alphanumeric'
```

(surrounded by quote and has one or more dots between alphanumeric words)

and another regex to find strings with the form

```
'this is a regular sentence with space'
```

I'm new to regex and have the following pattern which doesn't work. Which should mean:

(' + anything + . + anything + ')

```
/'*[^.]*'
```

I need multiple words with . connecting them.

Comment: Like this? `'\w+(?:\.\w+)+'` https://regex101.com/r/AZjbcE/1 If you want to match either with only dots or only spaces `'\w+(?:([. ])\w+(?:\1\w+)*)?'` https://regex101.com/r/dhTRgU/1

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Can you give us the expected result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern that you tried `/'*[^.]*'`  matches a `/`, then optional occurrences of `'` followed by optional chars other than `'` and match a `'` so a dot can not be matched.

---

You could use 2 separate patterns matching either a dot or a space at the start of the group and matching alphanumerics `[^\W_]+` exluding the underscore from a word character.

```
'[^\W_]+(?:\.[^\W_]+)+'
```

Another option is to use a capture group matching either a dot or space and use a backreference in the repetition and match any letter or any number:

```
'[\p{L}\p{N}]+([.\p{Zs}\t])[\p{L}\p{N}]+(?:\1[\p{L}\p{N}]+)*'
```

- `'` Match literally
- `[\p{L}\p{N}]+` Match 1+ alphanumerics
- `([.\p{Zs}\t])[\p{L}\p{N}]+` Capture **group 1**, match either `.` or a space and 1+ alphanumerics
- `(?:\1[\p{L}\p{N}]+)*` Optionally match what is captured in group 1 using the backreference `\1` followed by 1+ alphanumerics
- `'` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uph0lx/1)

Comment: is `\p{}` supported in JavaScript/VSC

Comment: @rioV8 I tested this in my Visual studio code 1.53.2 and it worked for me.