# Matching html tags with regex in vscode

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have the regex `<meta[^>]*content="[^"]+">` and would like to use it with vscode search and replace to remove the `content` attribute from the `meta` tags. It works fine when the tag is on one line only:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

The problem is that it doesn't work for tags that span multiple lines like:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" 
    content="IE=edge">
```

Can i modify it to also work with multiline tags?

Comment: What regex variant are you using? Typically you would solve this with a multiline flag

Comment: I don't know which regex variation the built in vscode search and replace tool uses.

Comment: because it supports some Perl extensions it is not the native JavaScript regex. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66583164/9938317

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Notice: You have to use the current file search with CTRL+F / CMD+F to use the following. Global file search with CTRL+SHIFT+F / CMD+SHIFT+F does not work due to lookbehind assertion without fixed length!**

You can use the following regex for searching:

```
(?<=<meta.*?)[\s\n]+content="[^"]+"
```

What it does:

```
[\s\n]+content="[^"]+" : Match all content attributes with its preceding white spaces and new lines
(?<=<meta.*?) : Look behind for opening meta tags and optionally other attributes in between
```

**Then simply replace with an empty string and your content attributes + preceding white spaces/new lines are gone.**

Tested with

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" 
    content="IE=edge">

<meta content="IE=edge">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" 
    content="IE=edge"
    name="test">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" 
    content="IE=edge" name="test">

<link content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: Actually it didn't work in VScode as lookbehinds can only be fixed length.

Comment: Did you actually try it out?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `<meta([^>]*)([\n\s\S])content="[^"]+">`.

I changed your regex by adding `[\n\s\S]` group that matches for any new line or any content